# projectNotLinked error when using Google Play API Explorer to issue refund

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to use Google Play Developer API (API explorer). Specifically talking about "orders.refund" API- I want to refund and revoke a single purchased IAP but getting the error below.

1. Went into Google Play Developer console
2. API access -> Created a new Google Cloud Project. Under APIs, I see "Google Play Android Developer API" set to "ON".
3. I click View API details which forwards me to my Google Cloud project where I see my Google Play Android Developer API
4. I click "Try in API explorer"
5. On the left side, I click order -> refund, and fill in the PackageName, orderID and revoke boolean field.
6. Google OAuth 2.0 and API Key are both checked, and I click EXECUTE
7. "Sign up with Google" dialog appears, I choose the same account I have, and then get the below error
8. Tried what other posts suggested a few years back- adding a new IAP product in Google Play Console, deleted it, but still no-go.

Anyone knows how to unblock me?

{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"domain": "androidpublisher",
"reason": "projectNotLinked"
}
]
}
}